# Проблема с позиционированием hover

Tags: html, css

Из-за недостатка опыта сижу и ломаю голову над проблемой.
Дело в том, что у меня есть блоки, при наведении которых сбоку выдвигается текст.
Код работает исправно, но я не могу поместить их рядом друг с другом.

```css
.card {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 300px;
  height: 400px;
  background: #262626;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.card .imgBx,
.card .details {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  transition: .5s;
}

.card .imgBx {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.card:hover .imgBx {
  top: 0;
  left: -100%;
}

.card .imgBx img {
  width: 100%;
}

.card .details {
  background: #262626;
  top: 0;
  left: 100%;
  padding: 60px 30px;
}

.card:hover .details {
  top: 0;
  left: 0%;
}

.card .details h5 {
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 0 10px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #fff;
}

.card .details span {
  margin: 20px 0 0;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
  <div class="imgBx">
    1232ds
  </div>
  <div class="details">
    <h5>What is Lorem Ipsum?</h5>
    <span>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Если быть точнее, то хотелось бы допустим 3 таких блока подряд установить

Comment: Таких - это каких? как называется класс у такого блока?

Comment: Нужно 3 блока card установить в ряд

Comment: Так они absolute, надо без этого их верстать

Comment: @МихаилКамахин, не правильно формулируйте, надо правильно верстать с использованием `position: absolute`, а с Ваших слов можно вообще ставить крест на данном правиле)

Comment: @De.Minov в такой реализации как у автора - нельзя использовать и на этом надо крест ставить, да

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это же не проблема, смотрите используем flexbox и по hover показываем

> Оба примера смотрим на весь экран

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.card {
  width: 200px;
  height: 300px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 20px;
}

.details {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  right: -250px;
  transition: 0.34s linear;
}

.card:hover .details {
  right: -10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="imgBx">
      1232ds
    </div>
    <div class="details">
      <h5>What is Lorem Ipsum?</h5>
      <span>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="imgBx">
      1232ds
    </div>
    <div class="details">
      <h5>What is Lorem Ipsum?</h5>
      <span>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="imgBx">
      1232ds
    </div>
    <div class="details">
      <h5>What is Lorem Ipsum?</h5>
      <span>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Второй вариант - так же покажем по hover но для сетки используем grid

https://codepen.io/topicstarter/pen/XWpxaaX

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.grid {
  width: 100%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  justify-items: center;
}

.item,
video,
img {
  display: block;
  width: 250px;
  height: 350px;
}

.item {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.hide {
  position: absolute;
  left: 100%;
  top: 0;
  transition: 0.34s cubic-bezier(1, 0, 0, 1.2);
  width: 250px;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background: #fff;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.hide-text {
  padding: 10px;
}

.item:hover .hide {
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="item">
    <h2>Смотрим youtube</h2>
    <div class="hide">
      <video preload controls src="https://vod-progressive.akamaized.net/exp=1618942543~acl=%2Fvimeo-prod-skyfire-std-us%2F01%2F2894%2F18%2F464474575%2F2059361374.mp4~hmac=cdbf4bdba852c122a7b26141b6d47f47449e11fcd43805538467bb44e450f1d2/vimeo-prod-skyfire-std-us/01/2894/18/464474575/2059361374.mp4?filename=pexels-amina-filkins-5510488.mp4"></video>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <h2>Смотрим картинку</h2>
    <div class="hide">
      <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/2569241/pexels-photo-2569241.jpeg?cs=srgb&dl=pexels-luis-leon-2569241.jpg&fm=jpg" alt="">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <h2>Читаем текст</h2>
    <div class="hide hide-text">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Recusandae debitis ducimus asperiores officia, assumenda magni enim itaque dicta quae esse!
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```